# How do we read headers from boost websocket servers in C++

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, header

Ive been trying to write a server for a client that uses websockets. 
Currently the client code is similar to :

```
ws.async_handshake_ex(handshake_response,hostname,"/",
[this](websocket::request_type& request) { 
request.set("header1","value1");
request.set("header2","value2");
},
function_after_handshake());
```

Now, on my server side I've been trying to use these values of headers. I've been trying to write code like so :

```
ws.async_accept_ex(
      [this](websocket::response_type& res) {
         cout<<res.base().get("header1");
      },
      function_after_handshake_server());
```

Obviously this is wrong, but what would be the correct way to do this on server side?
I cannot change client code(totally not mine), and thus can't use latest versions of boost.

Comment: WebSocket uses HTTP for establishing a connection. When `Connection: Upgrade` is specified in the header, the hosts change their protocol from HTTP to WebSocket. So, to read values from the header, you should accept socket with HTTP and pass the response to WebSocket accept function. Boost::Beast has a function overload for this.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a function `boost::beast::websocket::is_upgrade` that checks whether the given response is requesting for WebSocket.

Comment: @paxbun I don't want to check for a request for websocket. I know it is. I have custome header values I'm trying to read.

Comment: So that header values are sent within the request, aren't they? Then you should accept the connection as HTTP, read header value, and change protocol into WebSocket. Also, `websocket::response_type` is an alias for `http::response<http::string_body>`.

Comment: @paxbun yep thats what I figured. 
I'm getting websocket::is_upgrade returning false so that's a problem I'm trying to overcome